# a href tag inside td tag in php

Tags: php, hyperlink

The every part of code works fine except  that i want to go to next page with query to delete the entry. The echoing of td works fine for text , which I want to work as a link.

```
<?php

$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbms_teacher",$connect);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT fname,lname,post,status FROM staffs");
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Post</td><td>Status</td><td>Edit      /Delete</td></tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['post']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['status']. "</td>";
    echo "<td> delete </td>"; //In this line, I want to hyperlink it to some other page
    echo "</tr>";
}
mysql_close($connect);
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: You already wrote HTML in your code, what prevented you from writing a link also?

Comment: For 100th time, mysql_* is deprecated, dont use fetch_array when not needed! use fetch_assoc instead... You've done PHP and cant put a href html tag? :)) How are you learning programming? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use HTML markup in your PHP

`"<td> delete </td>";`

```
"<td><a href='http://yourlink'>delete</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbms_teacher",$connect);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT fname,lname,post,status FROM staffs");
echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Post</td><td>Status</td><td>Edit          /Delete</td></tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['fname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['lname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['post']. "</td>";
    echo "<td>". $row['status']. "</td>";
    echo "<td><a href="delete.php?id=$row['id']">Delete</a></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
}
mysql_close($connect);
echo "</table>";
```

?>

Comment: doesnot take the ?id=$row['id'] part

Comment: because you didn't include it in your query.. use this SELECT id,fname,lname,post,status FROM staffs

Answer (score 0):

This will suffice.

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php'>delete</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
echo "<td><a href='index.php?action=etc'>delete</a> | <a href='index.php?action=etc'>edit</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"<td><a href='http://yourlink'>delete</a></td>";
```

From the look of it,
it should be like this.

Comment: Care to explain your answer?

Answer (score -2):

```
<td><a href="welcome.php"><?php echo $row['id'];?></a><td>
      here in this example<?php echo $row['id'];? is used
 by this we fetching  a value from db
and ha h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h h standard blockquote is indented
> > A nested block
```